# How can i get the parent key and value if i already have children value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, array-key

I am unable to figure out how to get the parent key and value with the help of it's child's key value of multidimensional array.

I have an array in the format like this:

```
[91] => Array
    (
        [description] => Charged
        [boundingPoly] => Array
            (
                [vertices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 244
                                [y] => 438
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 287
                                [y] => 438
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 287
                                [y] => 452
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 244
                                [y] => 452
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

I am getting and storing the value of the key ['x']:

```
foreach($array as $box){
     if($box['description']=="Charged"){
            $lbl_row_arr[] = $box['boundingPoly']['vertices'][0]['x'];
     }
}
```

So now i have value of 'x' in this example is "244". My question is how can i get the value of 'description' key if i have the value of 'x'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array` with `array_column` to search the `x` values for each box, returning the `description` for that box if the `x` value is found:

```
$x = 244;
foreach ($array as $box) {
    if (in_array($x, array_column($box['boundingPoly']['vertices'], 'x'))) {
        $descr = $box['description'];
        break;
    }
}
if (isset($descr)) {
    echo "found $descr with x = $x\n";
}
```

Output (for your sample entry):

```
found Charged with x = 244
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2dJbv)

Answer (score 1):

Put `description` value with `x` value at the same time:

```
foreach($array as $box){
     if($box['description']=="Charged"){
            $tmp = [
                'value_x' => $box['boundingPoly']['vertices'][0]['x'],
                'descr'   => $box['description'], 
            ];
            $lbl_row_arr[] = $tmp;
     }
}

$x = 244;
echo $lbl_row_arr[array_search($x,array_column($lbl_row_arr,'value_x'))]['descr'];
```